# pandas groupby.size() not working expected

Tags: python, pandas

I have been through a very wired situation when I was using df.groupby

Wonder someone could give me some hint on this, thanks!

This the first few lines of my data frame:
[order_N_time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDap7.png)

This is my code:

```
orders = pd.read_csv('./order_N_time.csv', delimiter='\t')
grouped = orders.groupby(['SalesID']).size()

print(grouped)
```

The result is wired is because, it has jumped over some values! Like this

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t61nx.png)

Based on my understanding of groupby there should be some value between 1-1 to 10-1, such as 2-1. But it did not appear in the output.

Could somebody give me some advice for that, thanks!

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to create a minimum reproducible example

Comment: Have you scrolled through the entire result of size() output? Maybe it is just sorting 1s first and then 2s? Maybe.

Comment: It should be there, 10-1 comes before 2-1 if sorted

Comment: You probably want `orders.groupby('SalesID', sort=False).size()` (notice the `sort` argument).